# What are the minimum requirements to create a "standalone" installer for pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, installing, standalone

I prefer to use [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) for my plotting needs, but I tend to use LaTeX for my documents as well, so I have the full TeX Live installed. I'd like to convince my friends/lab mates/colleagues to use `pgfplots` as well, instead of Gnuplot or MATLAB or Origin or...

What are the minimal requirements to install `pgfplots` in a "standalone" manner, and what procedure should I follow to install this on a computer with no TeX distribution installed? I would prefer to use a `.zip` file that can be unzipped and any binaries added to the system path, rather than trying to install a minimal TeX distribution, since (I think!) that will be the easiest procedure, similar to installing Gnuplot with an installer.

Let's assume for now that I want PDF output with support for system fonts (i.e. `lualatex` or `xelatex` with [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) preferred). I presume the procedure will be similar to [creating a portable installation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) (e.g., on a USB stick), but those instructions will install all of TeX Live, when I just want `pgfplots`.

This question asks about installing the `pgfplots` package in the home directory, so is related, but does not include the `*latex` binaries: [How can I install pgfplots on the home directory with or without sudo rights?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97765/32374/how-can-i-install-pgfplots-on-the-home-directory-with-or-without-sudo-rights)

Comment: You will (anyway) need a basic TeX installation (for miktex, it is basic miktex) and then install `pgfplots` using package manager.

Comment: @HarishKumar Is there any way I can package up the minimal amount from the TeX distribution into a separate "installer" (zip file is fine)? See my edit. Thanks! :-)

Comment: For miktex there is a basic installer and I don't know about texlive. And packaging by yourselves... well you will get lot of headache ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar I want the headache! :-) At least to try it, to learn more about how TeX is put together

Comment: You need a minimal `tex` distribution. Then you can unzip the pgfplots `.tds` zip into the "local texmf" directory (linux: `~/texmf`, windows also has it somewhere) and then run `texhash`. Keep in mind that you also need PGF (which can also be installed into a local `texmf` tree).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger care to convert your comment to an answer for this one?

Answer (score 3):

You need a minimal tex distribution. Then you can unzip the pgfplots .tds zip into the "local texmf" directory (linux: ~/texmf, windows also has it somewhere) and then run texhash. Keep in mind that you also need PGF (which can also be installed into a local texmf tree).