# usepgfplotslibrary{filebetween} does not work

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to fill the area below a given curve. The compiles pdflatex complains saying the proper usepgfplotlibrary has not been used. See the code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.1]
    \addplot[name path=f,domain=-.15:1.05,blue] {x^2};

    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);

    \addplot [
        thick,
        color=blue,
        fill=blue, 
        fill opacity=0.05
    ]
    fill between[
        of=f and axis,
        soft clip={domain=0:1},
    ];

    \node [rotate=48] at (axis cs:  .7,  .59) {$y=x^2$};
    \node [rotate=90] at (axis cs:  1.05,  .25) {$x=1$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

The error

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Please load \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} in order
 to use `\addplot fill between'..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25     ];
```

Comment: Your snippet runs without problems on my TeXLive 2017 distribution.

Comment: Working in TeXLive 2015 too.

Comment: The latest texlive version for ubuntu 17.10 does not work. I had to download the pgfplots package, unzip that and redirect TEXINPUT as explaind in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97765/how-can-i-install-pgfplots-on-the-home-directory-with-or-without-sudo-rights.

Comment: Have you checked the LOG file that you are really using at least PGFPlots v1.10?